# Having trouble doing a search and replace in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, replace

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and trying to do a regular expression search and replace.  If my variable starts out like so …

```
url = “http://results.mydomain.com/json/search?eventId=974&subeventId=2320&callback=jQuery18305053194007595733_1464633458265&sEcho=3&iColumns=13&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=1&iDisplayLength=100&mDataProp_0=“
```

and then I run that through

```
display_start = url.match(/iDisplayStart=(\d+)/).captures[0] 
display_start = display_start.to_i + 1000
url = url.gsub(/iDisplayStart=(\d+)/) { display_start }
```

The result is

```
http://results.mydomain.com/json/search?eventId=974&subeventId=2320&callback=jQuery18305053194007595733_1464633458265&sEcho=3&iColumns=13&sColumns=&1001&iDisplayLength=100&mDataProp_0=
```

But what I want is to simply replace the “iDisplayStart” parameter with my new value, so I would like the result to be

```
http://results.mydomain.com/json/search?eventId=974&subeventId=2320&callback=jQuery18305053194007595733_1464633458265&sEcho=3&iColumns=13&sColumns=&1001&iDisplayStart=1001&iDisplayLength=100&mDataProp_0=
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with

```
url = "http://results.mydomain.com/json/search?eventId=974&subeventId=2320&callback=jQuery18305053194007595733_1464633458265&sEcho=3&iColumns=13&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=1&iDisplayLength=100&mDataProp_0="
display_start = url.sub(/(?<=iDisplayStart=)\d+/) {|m| m.to_i+1000}
puts  display_start
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/jiRYue)

Since you replace 1 substring, you do not need `gsub`, a `sub` will do.

The block takes the whole match (that is,  1 or more digits that are located before `iDisplayStart`), `m`, and converts to an int value that we add `1000` to inside the block.

Another way is to use your regex (or add `\b` for a safer match) and access the captured vaalue with `Regexp.last_match[1]` inside the block:

```
url = "http://results.mydomain.com/json/search?eventId=974&subeventId=2320&callback=jQuery18305053194007595733_1464633458265&sEcho=3&iColumns=13&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=1&iDisplayLength=100&mDataProp_0="
display_start = url.sub(/\biDisplayStart=(\d+)/) {|m| "iDisplayStart=#{Regexp.last_match[1].to_i+1000}" }
puts  display_start
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Uc8OBR)